# Bind holding `SPACE` to `CTRL`, pressing/releasing `SPACE` to " "

Tags: xkb

I am using Archlinux.

For ergonomic reasons I am looking for a possibility to use `xkb` to map holding the space bar to the CTRL modifier and pressing and releasing the space bar to insert a " ".

So typing `SPC + x` would be cutting marked text.
But typing `SPC` would insert the " " character.

Is it possible to do this with `xkb`? Do I have to use some different tool?

Comment: `xmodmap` can make the spacebar into a `Ctrl` key but then the spacebar would not work as a space character.  Probably the best you can achieve is to have a combination (e.g. `<spacebar> + M` should be ergonomic on a qwerty keyboard) to produce the space character.  The `Ctrl` function is quite special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The software [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) can do that.

```
$ apt-cache search xcape
xcape - Configure modifier keys to act as other keys when pressed and released
```

With the keyword `xcape` you'll find how-tos for most desires

Comment: `xcape` is awesome, it runs as a daemon and (therefore) has `-t` (for timeout) which `xmodmap` (plain `xkb`) does not.  Just note that OP is on Arch Linux, so he needs to go through the [`xcape build from AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xcape/) with `makepkg` and `pacman`.